# How do you use mask of many faces?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, warlock

My warlock thinks he can use Mask of Many Faces to cast Disguise Self an unlimited number of times each day, and that the effect will last for a whole day.

Is his understanding of this invocation correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, he can cast *disguise self* an unlimited number of times per day. But it doesn't last a whole day.

> You
>   can
>   cast
>   *disguise
>   self*
>   at
>   will,
>   without
>   expending
>   a
>   spell
>   slot.

This only lets him cast *disguise self*, it doesn't modify the spell at all. And *disguise self* says:

> Duration:
>   1
>   hour

So while he can indeed cast it an unlimited number of times, it only lasts an hour each time.

Comment: Couldn't he just cast it again before it runs out, essentially letting it last as long as he wants so long as he's able to recast it?

Comment: @MagRoader Sure! But that wasn't the question.

Comment: @MagRoader It also still requires verbal and somatic components. People might wonder why you keep gesturing and chanting every hour or so.

Comment: Well sure but that's easy to work around. Bathroom break, walk to a corner, whatever.

Comment: @Mag Roader: While it's easy to work around, it's important to keep in mind, and it can create a dramatic Cinderella at Midnight effect.